# Using a specific version of MSBuild in a FAKE build script

Tags: f#, msbuild, f#-fake

I currently have VS2013 and VS2015 installed on my machine.

By default FAKE F# Make seems to be building with VS2015.

I tried passing into my MSBuild task the VisualStudioVersion 12.0 but that didn't seem to have any effect.

I saw some articles say to change the MSBuildPath in the Fake.exe.config but I don't see the MSBuildPath in that exe.

How do I make sure it uses the MSBuild provided with Visual Studio 2012 (12.0)?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you care what version of MSBuild gets called?  It should still build for the project specified target .net platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
    let toolsVersion = "12.0"

    let setParams defaults =
        { defaults with
            ToolsVersion = Some(toolsVersion)
        }

    build setParams solutionPath
        |> DoNothing
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew code didn't change MSBuild version for me. I figure out another way do achieve this.

```
EnvironmentHelper.setBuildParam "VisualStudioVersion" "14.0"
```

You could also use **"12.0"** for vs2013 or **"15.0"** for vs2017.
Here is [link to Fake source](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/MSBuildHelper.fs#L104) that use this variable during the build.